How to deal with warnings when doing ANOVA
I get the following warning message :
Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you 
  specified a well-considered value for the type argument to 
  ezANOVA().Warning: Collapsing data to cell means. *IF* the requested
   effects are a subset of the full design, you must use the 
  "within_full" argument, else results may be inaccurate.Coefficient
   covariances computed by hccm()

I am doing a one-way ANOVA on Chickweight built in dataset from which I cut the time column. I used the following function:
ezANOVA(data = cw, 
    dv = weight, 
    wid = Chick,
    between = Diet, 
    type = 2,
    return_aov = TRUE,
    detailed = TRUE)

Can I ignore the warning or should I change something in my code?

I tried to run this and got a potentially much more serious error that the library broom (which has ezANOVA) is corrupt.
Why are you using this rather obscure library when ANOVA is available in, e.g. stats ?

Also, it is never a good idea to just ignore warnings.

I used the ez library because that is how I found ANOVA done in a book. Okay I will try to use the stats library. Thank you.

I did receive an output , sum of squares, degrees of freedom and residual standard error. Now to complete the analysis, should I interpret these results?

I don't have a model for this dataset, I think this is a problem and I should construct it, but how?

If you ran an ANOVA you have a model. Your model is in your code.

check table(ChickWeight$Diet) . You'll see that, just as ezANOVA says that the Diet levels are unbalanced. This may have consequences to the reliability of your test statistics, see e.g. here. That's why you get a warning. You'll have to decide whether the warning is relevant.

@Sointu Thank you so much! I appreciate it.

ANOVA is usually rather robust to small differences in cell sizes. However, if the variances between different Diet levels are unequal - you can check this for instance by using levene.test function from the car package levene.test(weight ~ Diet, data=ChickWeight)  - then it may not be robust and you should use e.g. robust ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis instead.
